# creating a static measure to get values in power bi dax

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I have the below two tables in power bi as below

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table2]

based on the above two tables I want to create a matrix visual that should look like the image below "Output Matrix":

[image: Output Matrix]

I also have a slicer for a month, based on the month column from Table 1, what I want is in the output matrix visual the "Total Users" should remain constant value when we change the month and the rest of the columns values change based on the month selected in the slicer.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following 3 measures:

Measure 1

```
Active Users = DISTINCTCOUNT( Table1[user_id] ) + 0
```

Measure 2

```
Total Users = COUNT( Table2[user_id] ) + 0
```

Measure 3

```
Active Users % = DIVIDE( [Active Users], [Total Users], 0 )
```

Then create a Matrix Visual and drag the Manager column and the 3 measures.

This is the final output:
[image]